# Symfony - uploading a file sends me to _wtd url

Tags: symfony, upload

Every time I post to this controller, it redirects me to a /api/_wdt/XYZ123 page which errors out

```
/**
 * @Route("/import")
 */
class ImportController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/import", name="import_import", methods={"POST"})
     */
    public function import(Request $request): Response
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $file = $request->files->get('file');
        $filename = $file->getRealPath();

    }
}
```

why does it redirect.  I am only uploading a file, this doesnt happen when I am using a controller normally, it doesnt seem to like the file.

Answer (score 0):

There was more to the controller and it was erroring out.  For some reason the ajax gotr redirected to the profiler after the error.